# How to get first 2 children of a parent in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table that looks like the below

```
ID          Name          ParentID
333          UK            NULL
124         Wales          333
126        Swansea         124
127       Llanrhidian      126
```

As you can see all of the parent and children are in the same table. I need to create a view from this which shows the ID and name for each bottom level Child, the ChildID and Name of the one above it and then the highest level parent of them. An output of the above for Wales would look like the following

```
ChildID1     Child1Name     ChildID2     Child2Name   ParentID   ParentName
 127        Llanrhidian     126          Swansea        333        England
```

Sometimes the number of parents to a child can be different. In the example above, ChildID 127 has 3 parents. This can sometimes be more but we will always need to see the lowest 2.

Does this make sense? Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What have you already tried? Can you provide some code?

Comment: I tried using this solution but could get it to do what I needed as I wasn't sure how to get just the first 2 childs

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45661314/how-to-create-query-from-parent-child-hierarchy-table

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use CTE recursive with condition aggravated function.

the first query to use CTE recursive get all recursive relation data.

the second query use `MAX` window function to get max number which means parentId.

```
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT t1.ID,t1.Name,t1.ParentID,1 num
    FROM T t1 LEFT JOIN T t2 on t1.ID = t2.ParentID
    WHERE t2.ID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t2.ID,t2.NAME,t2.ParentID,num + 1
    FROM  CTE t1 JOIN T t2 ON t1.ParentID = t2.ID
),CTE2 AS (

    SELECT *,MAX(num) OVER(ORDER BY num desc) maxNum
    FROM CTE
)
SELECT  MAX(CASE WHEN num = 1 then  ID END) ChildID1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN num = 1 then  name END) Child1Name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN num = 2 then  ID END) ChildID2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN num = 2 then  Name END) Child2Name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN num = maxNum then  ID END) ParentID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN num = maxNum then  Name END) ParentName
FROM CTE2
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0a8a7e270a54d19b83ad703b4a0f6125)

Comment: I have used this but it seems to be taking a long time to run

Comment: Only 3000 rows. It is giving me the below error message.
The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion

Comment: I have added the option (maxrecursion 0) but this just doesnt let the query run

Comment: Any further help regarding the query not running? Many thanks

Comment: Did you got the same error when you add option(maxrecursion 0) at the end?

Comment: Yes it didn't run at all.

Comment: The table has 3600 rows

Comment: Are you sure there are no cyclic references in your data?

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL, use: `SELECT TOP 2 * FROM ...`
This wil only fetch the first 2 lines he finds. (This is syntax for SQL Server)