# Create hierarchy slicer in power bi using parent -child id from same column

Tags: parent-child, powerbi-desktop, hierarchy, slicers, data-transform

I have a sample data as follows
I need to create a hierarchical slicer using the name field based on the parent id and id

| id | parent Id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | A |
| 2 | null | B |
| 3 | 1 | a1 |
| 4 | 1 | a2 |
| 5 | 3 | a1-1 |
| 6 | 3 | a1-2 |
| 7 | 4 | a2-1 |
| 8 | 4 | a2-2 |
| 9 | 2 | b1 |
| 10 | 2 | b2 |
| 11 | 9 | b1-1 |
| 12 | 9 | b1-2 |
| 13 | 10 | b2-1 |
| 14 | 10 | b2-2 |

I am expecting a slicer as follows:

- A*(top-level)*

  - a1*(second-level)*

    - a1-1
    - a1-2
  - a2 *(second-level)

    - a2-1
    - a2-2
- B*(top-level)

  - b1*(second-level)

    - b1-1
    - b1-2
  - b2*(second-level)

    - b2-1
    - b2-2

I have tried using DAX PATH which does not work on direct query mode, I was able to create a column Level of hierarchy with values 0,1,2( Not in a very accurate way). But unsure and experimenting how to create the slicer using the level of hierarchy.

I would appreciate if someone can help me to achieve this. It would also be helpful if anyone can tell me how to establish a relationship between these parent and child ids and creating levels of hierarchy

Note: The data is in direct query mode hence some of the transformations are not possible( but welcoming answers in working with both import and direct query mode for my knowledge). THANKS IN Advance

Comment: You have to build table before (with Level1, Level2, Level3... columns).
1. Preferable way to build this table is [SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45661741/6165594]), as far as [recursion is NOT available in DAX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64198103/6165594).
2. if you have to build it on DAX level, please use [parent-child hierarchies in DAX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/understanding-functions-for-parent-child-hierarchies-in-dax) (you will need `PATH` and `PATHITEM` functions set).